# I am having issues using the functión DATEADD

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is a very simple question. The thing is that the error is allegedly produced because the first parameter of the fuction DATEADD is not a [DATE] column. This means that other types of dates like month or year won´t work as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it has to be an actual date to use the date add function. Just a year or just a month will not work. To add months you could use the function EDATE. See more here https://dax.guide/edate/